# Scroll UIScrollView faster when scrolling it through another view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIScrollView` with large `UIImageView` with image of very high resolution (about 10,000 x 10,000). In this `UIImageView` both zooming and scrolling is enabled. I also have a smaller `UIImageView` with the same image with much smaller resolution (about 100 x 100). I'm showing the visible portion of larger `UIImageView` on the smaller `UIImageView`. And the user can navigate to other places on larger `UIImageView` by panning on smaller `UIImageView`. The following images show what I'm trying to explain. My issue is the while panning on the smaller UIImageView the scrolling in larger UIScrollView really slow.
[image]

```
// function that handles the pan on green view
func handlePanNavigation(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: navigationPanel)
        guard let gv = gestureRecognizer.view else { return }
        let point = CGPoint(x: gv.center.x + translation.x, y: gv.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.view?.center = point
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: navigationPanelView)

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: orgSize.width*tiledScrollView.zoomScale/navSize.width, y: orgSize.height*tiledScrollView.zoomScale/navSize.height)
        let offset = navigationPanelView.frame.origin.applying(transform)
        tiledScrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **should not animate** the change of the content offset while applying a transformation of a user input real-time, since that can easily slow down the feedback.

Change

```
tiledScrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
```

to

```
tiledScrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain how you want to accomplish this but if you want to slow-down or speed-up a pan gesture translation, add a multiplier.

```
switch gesture.state {

    case .began:
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)

    case .changed:

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)

        if someView.frame.origin.y < someThreshold {
            someView.center = CGPoint(x: someView.center.x, y: someView.center.y + (translation.y * 0.25))
        }

    ...
```

Here, any pan upward beyond `someThreshold` is 4x slower. In your case, obviously, add a multiplier greater than 1.

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't give the desired result. The issue being while we input a pan gesture the larger view doesn't transition the viewable area to desired area.